# What is the merchant id?

Tags: windows-8, paypal

I'm having issues getting paypal integrated into my windows 8 app. I'm not sure what the "merchantId" is suppose to be, I'm assuming the terminology doesn't line up with what is on the developer portal?

In this code sample, Execute() returns false without showing any prompt:

```
BuyNow buyNow = new BuyNow([I've tried several ids I found from the portal])
{
    UseSandbox = true,
};

ItemBuilder itemBuilder = new ItemBuilder(this.product.Name);
itemBuilder.Description(this.product.Description);
itemBuilder.Name(this.product.Name);
itemBuilder.Price((product.SalePrice ?? product.Price).ToString());
itemBuilder.Quantity(1);
itemBuilder.ID (this.product.Id.ToString());
Item item = itemBuilder.Build();
buyNow.AddItem(item);

bool buyNowResult = await buyNow.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, for the next person. The 'MerchantId' refers to 'Merchant account ID' which is found on the www.sandbox.paypal.com site under Profile -> My Business Info.

I was also having issues because the string I was entering for the description was too long. Be sure to hook up to the error event to get a meaningful error message. The BuyNow object isn't populated with the error message despite it having an Error property.

```
buyNow.Error += (sender, e) =>
{
    // e has the error
};
```